# How to split table cell td using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi i am stuck on how to split a table cell on a table that is dynamically generated. This how far i have come:

```
   function splitcell(){

    var tableid = localStorage.getItem('value');

    var table = document.getElementById(tableid);

    var td = table.querySelectorAll('td.highlight');

    if(td.length > 1){

   alert("You cannot split two highlighted cells at a time. Please choose one cell to split at a     time"); 

  }
 var clone =  td[0].cloneNode(true);

 alert(clone.outerHTML);

 }
```

html table

```
   <table id="ideaef0" class="table-striped" style="margin-left: -120px; width: 950px; margin-top: 30px;" onclick="RealClickHandler(this)" border="1">
   <thead>
   <tr>
     <th id="thid55e9e" class="ui-resizable">
        <input type="text" class="header-input" placeholder="Edit Header 1"><span></span>
        
     </th>
     <th id="thid55e9e" class="ui-resizable">
        <input type="text" class="header-input" placeholder="Edit Header 2"><span></span>
      
     </th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td class="ui-resizable" contenteditable="true">
     
     </td>
     <td class="ui-resizable" contenteditable="true">
     
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td class="ui-resizable" contenteditable="true">
    
      </td>
      <td class="ui-resizable" contenteditable="true">
       
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td class="ui-resizable" contenteditable="true">
     
     </td>
     <td class="ui-resizable" contenteditable="true">
       
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="ui-resizable" contenteditable="true">
      
     </td>
     <td class="ui-resizable" contenteditable="true">
        
     </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

I will like to split cells horizontally and vertically. I know the idea should be while duplicating td it should colspan or rowspan the other tds. I need help with this

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

Find the table cell (td) you want to split.

Create a new td element.

Update the content of the original and new td elements accordingly.

Insert the new td element after the original td in the same row.

```
function splitCell() {
    var tableId = localStorage.getItem('value');
    var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
    var td = table.querySelectorAll('td.highlight');

    if (td.length !== 1) {
        alert("Please choose one cell to split at a time.");
        return;
    }

    var originalCell = td[0];
    var newRow = originalCell.parentNode.cloneNode(true); // Clone the entire row

    
    var newCell = document.createElement('td');
    newCell.className = 'ui-resizable';
    newCell.contentEditable = true;
    newCell.innerHTML = ''; 

    
    originalCell.parentNode.insertBefore(newCell, originalCell.nextSibling);

    
    originalCell.innerHTML = ''; 


    alert("Cell split successfully.");
}
```